# После добавления значения в ini файл с помощью configparser остальные значения записываются в скобки

Tags: python-3.x, ini

Хочу добавить значение в имеющийся ini файл с помощью модуля configparser

Изначально файл выглядит так

```
[RC]
server = test_server
port = 30000
```

Добавляю параметр

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('FILE.ini')
config.set('RC', 'group', 'test')
with open('FILE.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

После этого файл начинает выглядеть так:

```
[RC]
server = ['test_server']
port = ['30000']
group = test
```

Как сделать чтобы значения не оборачивались в квадратные скобки? Финал должен выглядеть так:

```
[RC]
server = test_server
port = 30000
group = test
```

Заранее благодарю)

Comment: у меня ваш код отрабатывает правильно и в результате именно то содержимое, которое вы хотите получить

Comment: @MaxU, у меня так же, версия 3.9.0

Comment: Знаете, у меня тоже перестало повторятся, ничего не менял, python3.8. Не понимаю ничего, час до этого стреляло стабильно, сейчас перестало.

Comment: Кажется смог воспроизвести

Answer (score 1):

Такое возникает если в секции попадутся дублирующиеся записи, если отлавливать через
`except (configparser.DuplicateOptionError) as e:` и не ронять скрипт то итог будет таким.
Решение - избавиться от дублей, после чего все заработает

Comment: ИМХО. Проще хранить конфиги в json и не париться. Прекрасно читаются, замечательно редактируются и дампятся